# Bootstrap 5 Webpack plugins are not fully functional

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I imported the Bootstrap 5 plugin as documented using Webpack

```
import Offcanvas from '../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/offcanvas';
import Dropdown from '../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';
import ScrollSpy from '../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy';
```

The events are working fine as below:

```
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('myOffcanvas')
myOffcanvas.addEventListener('hidden.bs.offcanvas', function () {
  // do something...
})
```

But when I want to create an instance:

```
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('myOffcanvas')
var bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined
```

I would be grateful for any help in this matter

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution @kmw ?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Try `new Offcanvas()` instead of `new bootstrap.Offcanvas()`:

```
var bsOffcanvas = new Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
```

Yes, the [Bootstrap 5 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/#via-javascript) states you can use `bootstrap.Offcanvas`, but in your case, you don't import `bootstrap`, you import `Offcanvas` directly. That's why `bootstrap` isn't defined.